# Can we call it "quantization" when we specify Hilbert space and operators to write a classical field theory into a quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator, spin-models, quantization

Can we call it [quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(physics)) when we specify Hilbert space and operators to write a classical field theory into a quantum theory? Suppose there is a single spin 1/2 system with Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\hat{\sigma}^x$. In the Heisenberg picture, the dynamical equation of operator $\hat{\sigma}^z$ is $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\hat{\sigma}^z(t)=-4\hat{\sigma}^z(t).$$ Now we are only interested in the dynamics of expectation of $\hat{\sigma}^z$, and thus define $\phi(t)\equiv\langle\hat{\sigma}^z(t)\rangle$ to write down the action $$S[\phi,\dot{\phi}]=\int dt(\frac{\dot{\phi}^2}{2}-2\phi^2).$$

I wonder the relation between this action and the quantum spin system. Especially, can we treat the above quantum theory of spin as a "quantized" theory from the classical action $S[\phi,\dot{\phi}]$ in the sense that

(a) we choose the Hilbert space to be the one describing the quantum spin,

(b) we map $\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}$, respectively, to $\hat{\sigma}^z$ and $2\hat{\sigma}^y$, so that the "quantized" Hamiltonian will be the one of the above quantum spin.

If not, what is the status of the field theory?